# Merge Columns in VBA

Tags: excel, merge, multiple-columns, vba

I need to process a file which i get in the following manner everyday.

```
C1  C2          C3
618 970000000000    32
    970000000000    32

58  970000000000    23
    970000000000    23
    970000000000    23

15  970000000000    119
    970000000000    119
    970000000000    119
    970000000000    119

15  970000000000    17
    970000000000    17
```

I need to merge the cells in C3 based on the merge of C1. Please note that C1 is already merged.
I want it to look like the following

```
    C1  C2          C3
618 970000000000    32
    970000000000    

58  970000000000    23
    970000000000    
    970000000000    

15  970000000000    119
    970000000000    
    970000000000    
    970000000000    

15  970000000000    17
    970000000000
```

Is it possible to write a code in VBA?

Comment: This is similar to a group by out put in SQL. How do you get your input file? What is your intention of doing mergining? How are you going to use it?

Comment: It looks like you don't want to reduce the number of rows; you want to eliminate duplicate values in C3. And each block of values is separated by a blank row. If that's true, it seems eminently possible in VBA. You go to the Developer menu item in Excel (I'm referring to Excel 2010), click the Visual Basic button, then under the Insert menu item, select module. In the code window, type your VBA function.

Comment: @ BonCodigo... my intention is to make my work easier... those values are distracting when I'm doing my analysis.

Comment: @kermit, the values need not be duplicates. this is just one column that I have put here. There are 3 more columns with all different values

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data are in columns A to C, you can use this code:

```
Sub MergeMyCells()
firstRrow = 1
Range("C1").Select
lastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Cells(lastRow, 3).Select
For i = firstRow To lastRow
  Cells(i, 3).Select
  If (Not (ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value > 0)) Then
    ActiveCell.Value = ""
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You can remove the select statements in your for loop and replace the `ActiveCell` references with `Cells(i,3)` for better preformance